Problems with Android Studio Tutorial = Adding an Image
I am having difficulties with this portion of the tutorial on developer.Android.com. I am on the chapter about adding in an image to your app.
Adding an Image to an App
During the step, I am using the following code, just as stated in the tutorial.
@Composable
fun GreetingImage(message: String, from: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val image = painterResource(R.drawable.androidparty)
    Image(
        painter = image
    )
}

When doing this, if I hover over the Image keyword I get the following error -
Cannot access '': it is package-private in 'Image'
Cannot create an instance of an abstract class
as well as the following if I move the cursor over the painter keyword
Cannot create an instance of an abstract class
Named arguments are not allowed for non-Kotlin functions
Cannot find a parameter with this name: painter
Can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

set the image contentDescription string or null
Image(
    painter = image,     
    contentDescription = "" //your string or contentDescription = null
)


That solved the issue. Why didn't the tutorial mention having to have that line of code in there I wonder.
